# Issue with setOnItemClickListener event listener

Tags: android

I am trying to open a new activity when a user clicks on a value in a text view. Here the onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get change in selected projects group & show group accordingly
    RadioGroup rgProjectGroupsToLoad = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgProjectGroupsToLoad);
    rgProjectGroupsToLoad.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId)
        {
            // Get the vocab needed to provide options
            Resources res = getResources();
            String[] region_values = res.getStringArray(R.array.regions);
            String[] priority_values = res.getStringArray(R.array.priorities);
            String[] curr_values = region_values;

            TextView tvGroupingHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listRegionsPrioritiesHeader);

            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)rGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
            boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
            if (isChecked)
            {
                String selected_group = (String) checkedRadioButton.getText();
                Log.w("myApp", "Project Group selected: " + selected_group);
                tvGroupingHeader.setText(selected_group);
                if (selected_group.equals("Geographic Regions"))
                {
                    curr_values = region_values;
                }
                else
                {
                    curr_values = priority_values;
                }
                // Project Group Adapter for ListView
                ArrayAdapter<String> proj_group_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                        android.R.id.text1, 
                        curr_values
                );
                ListView lvRegionsPriorities = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRegionsPriorities);
                lvRegionsPriorities.setAdapter(proj_group_adapter); 

                // Show hidden elements
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listRegionsPrioritiesHeader);
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRegionsPriorities);
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried to set `lvRegionsPriorities.setOnItemClickListener` but that just produced many errors for which I couldn't find any results when googling.

So, can anybody help out here? How do I set the event listener properly?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in there where you are trying to start a new activity. I do see you trying to show hidden views on the same activity. You use Intents to start a new activity. If the issue is that your views aren't coming up when you click on it maybe try starting them out as visible and seeing if they show then. It could be something like that which wouldn't have to do with the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If the `TextView` is in your Activity:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(...);
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
})
```

If you want to open an activity when a given item is clicked in your `ListView`

Let your activity implement `OnItemClickListener()`
In `OnCreate()`:
     lvRegionsPriorities.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Somewhere else override:

```
public void onItemClick(View v, int position, long id){
     if (position == xx){ // check your condition here
         Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);         
     }
}
```